# How to add references to Excel VBA for Word programming

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro which uses the Word objects to create a Word document based on a Word template document.

I am having some difficulties when I use Option Explicit. Without it I can just omit the Dim ... line but I would like that there.

Here is the code so far:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateWordDoc()
    Dim wApp As Object
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document ' User-defined type not defined error on this line
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\path\WordTestTemplateDoc.dotx", ReadOnly:=False)

    With wDoc
        .Content.Find.Execute FindText:="<Project ID>", ReplaceWith:="This is the project id....."
        .SaveAs2 Filename:=("C:\path\NewWordDoc.docx"), FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: What you want is called "early binding". What you are currently doing is "late binding". The complete article can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference in the VBE to `Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library` as described in this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx

Afterwards, the VBE will even offer auto-completion as it does when you write code for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

OptionExplicit makes it so that you ABSOLUTELY MUST declare everything you use. By not adding the statement, you tell the VB compiler that it is in control of determining the types of variables that were never declared. This is somewhat lazy and could lead to potential problems. You should always declare all your variables.

Comment: Which is why I want to