# Adding a Hyperlink from an Excel file to a Word document using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink from Excel to Word.

I tried different anchors including ChBridge & "<< Chime Bridge Hyperlink >>" but all come out as errors.

Also, is there a way to combine the separate text replacements to neaten up the code?

The lookup to ChBridge is a http:\ address and already a hyperlink though that doesn't pull through when replacing the text.

```vb
Sub MailMerge()

Dim oWord As Object
Dim oSelection As Object
Dim D1Diff As Double
Dim Site, sAddr, ChBridge As String
    
Set WB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set Sett = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
Set RT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hiring Order")

LR = WB.Cells(WB.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        
For B = 3 To LR Step 1

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Documents.Open "*File Location*"
    oWord.Visible = True

    oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="Line " & B - 2 & ".docx",     FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

    'Site & Address Vlookup
    Site = RT.Range("B2")
    sAddr = Application.VLookup(Site, Sett.Range("D1:G3"), 4, 0)

    'Chime Bridge Vlookup
    ChBridge = Application.VLookup(Site, Sett.Range("D1:H3"), 5, 0)

    Set sel = oWord.Selection

    With sel
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With .Find
            .Text = "<<Chime Bridge Hyperlink>>"
            .Replacement.Text = ChBridge
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range, Address:=ChBridge
           sel.Find.Execute Replace:=2  'wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End With

    With sel
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With .Find
            .Text = "<<Site>>"
            .Replacement.Text = Site
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            sel.Find.Execute Replace:=2  'wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End With

    With sel
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With .Find
            .Text = "<<Address & Post Code>> "
            .Replacement.Text = sAddr
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            sel.Find.Execute Replace:=2  'wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End With

    oWord.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    oWord.Quit

Next B

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Site, sAddr, ChBridge As String` - In this declaration only `ChBridge` is a string, the other variables are variants. You need to explicitly type each variable in VBA, i.e. `Dim Site As String, sAddr As String, ChBridge As String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand all the find and replace, but this should get you started.

See how I declared the variables and assigned them their type.

Also see how I refer to the word application and it's objects

I used Early bound, so you need to add a reference to the Word Object Model ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800221/1521579))

```
Sub MailMerge()
    
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim settingsSheet As Worksheet
    Set settingsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
    
    Dim hiringOrderSheet As Worksheet
    Set hiringOrderSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hiring Order")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 3 To lastRow Step 1
        
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application
        Set wordApp = Word.Application
        wordApp.Visible = True
        
        Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\test.docx")
        
        wordDoc.SaveAs Filename:="Line " & counter - 2 & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
        
        'Site & Address Vlookup
        Dim site As String
        site = hiringOrderSheet.Range("B2").Value
        
        Dim siteAddress As String
        siteAddress = Application.VLookup(site, settingsSheet.Range("D1:G3").Value, 4, 0)
        
        'Chime Bridge Vlookup
        Dim ChBridge As String
        ChBridge = Application.VLookup(site, settingsSheet.Range("D1:H3").Value, 5, 0)
        
        Dim wordContent As Word.Range
        
        Set wordContent = wordDoc.Content
        
        wordContent.Find.ClearFormatting
        wordContent.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        
        With wordContent.Find
            .Text = "<<Chime Bridge Hyperlink>>"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1
            .Format = False
        End With
        
        wordContent.Find.Execute
        
        While wordContent.Find.Found
            wordContent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wordContent, Address:=ChBridge, TextToDisplay:=ChBridge
            wordContent.Find.Execute
        Wend
        
        wordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        wordApp.Quit
        
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, got it working - you are a star! :)